# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(ax)}}{x^b} dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{x^b} \, dx,\quad a\in \mathbb{R},\quad 0<b<2.$$

I know $a=1$ ,and $ b\in \mathbb{N}$, I can find the value,

How to evaluate this integral for general $a,b$?  Thank you.

Comment: The indefinite integral is sure to be *nasty* based on what http://integral-table.com/integral-table.html has for similar integrals. Maybe that improper integral will magically be nice somehow, though.

Comment: For $a\neq 0$ you may substitute $u=ax$; hence it suffices to solve the problem for $a=1$.

Comment: Yes,But $b\in R,0<b<2$

Comment: Wolfram gives $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^b}dx=\cos(\pi b/2)\Gamma(1-b)$.

Comment: Maple produces $${a}^{b-1}\Gamma  \left( 1-b \right) \cos \left( 1/2\,\pi \,b \right)  $$ for $a>0,\,0<b,\,b<2.$

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453811/integral-of-int-limits-0-infty-frac-sin-xn-xndx/454082#454082).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Process 1**:$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{x^b} \, dx.$$$$=-\Im\left(\int_0^\infty\large e^{-iax}x^{-b}\, dx\right)$$$$=-\Im\left(\frac{1}{(ia)^{1-b}}\int_0^\infty\large e^{-t}t^{-b}\, dt\right)$$$$=-\Im\left(\frac{1}{(ia)^{1-b}}\Gamma(1-b)\right)=a^{b-1}\Gamma(1-b)\cos \left({\pi b\over 2}\right)$$

**Process 2**: Use [Mellin Transformation](http://n.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform).

Let, $$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{x^b} \, dx=a^{b-1}\int_0^\infty \sin(x)x^{-b}\,dx$$
Now, using Mellin transformation of $\sin x$, we will have, $$I(a,b)=a^{b-1}\Gamma(1-b)\sin\left(\frac{\pi(1-b)}{2}\right)=a^{b-1}\Gamma(1-b)\cos \left({\pi b\over 2}\right)$$

Comment: I think there is a minus sign issue in front of the integral on the 3rd line.

Comment: Ah, corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Since the answer is in my line ... (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin x$ can be decomposed into the exponents $\exp(\pm i  a x)$, and transforming $i a x\to t$, you get an integral which is equivilent to the [Incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).