# Integrability of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1-\cos(x\cdot y)}{|x|^{n+q}}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Define $$I(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1-\cos(x\cdot y)}{|x|^{n+q}}dx$$ where $0<q<2$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{ 0\} $. I'm trying to show that $0<I(y)<\infty$ and $I(y) = c|y|^q$ for some constant c.

**My attempt**
We can switch to polar coordinates to deal with the integral in a one-dimensional setting.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1-\cos(x\cdot y)}{|x|^{n+q}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{S^{n-1}} \frac{1-\cos(r\cdot y)}{r^{n+q}} r^{n-1}d\sigma (x')dr \\ =\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(r\cdot y)}{r^{n+q}} r^{n-1}drd\sigma (x') \\ = \text{vol}(S^{n-1})\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(r\cdot y)}{r^{q+1}}dr$$
I'm not sure where to go from here... I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the argument of the cosine is a dot product between two $n$-dimensional vectors. It depends on the angle between $x$ and $y$, so we cannot simply replace $x$ by the radial coordinate $r$ when switching to polar coordinates. However, for a given $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ we can always rotate the $x$-coordinate system in such a way that $y$ points along the $x_1$-axis. Then $x \cdot y = \lvert y \rvert x_1$ holds and we obtain
$$ I (y) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1 - \cos(\lvert y \rvert x_1)}{\lvert x \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} x \, ,$$
since the Lebesgue measure is invariant under rotations. Introducing $z = \lvert y \rvert x$, we find the desired result
$$ I(y) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1 - \cos(z_1)}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z \, \frac{\lvert y \rvert^{n+q}}{\lvert y \rvert^n} \equiv c \lvert y \rvert^q \, .$$
Clearly, we have
$$ c = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1 - \cos(z_1)}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z > 0 \, ,$$
since the integrand is positive almost everywhere. $c < \infty$ follows as in GReyes' answer and we can even give an explicit estimate:
\begin{align}
c &= \int \limits_{B_1(0)} \frac{1 - \cos(z_1)}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z + \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_1(0)} \frac{1 - \cos(z_1)}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z \leq \int \limits_{B_1(0)} \frac{z_1^2}{2\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z + \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_1(0)} \frac{2}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{B_1(0)} \frac{1}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q-2}} \, \mathrm{d} z + 2 \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_1(0)} \frac{1}{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}} \, \mathrm{d} z = \operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \left[\frac{1}{2} \int \limits_0^1 r^{1-q} \, \mathrm{d} r + 2 \int \limits_1^\infty r^{-(1+q)} \, \mathrm{d} r\right] \\
&= \operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \left[\frac{1}{2(2-q)} + \frac{2}{q}\right] = \operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}) \frac{8-3q}{2 q (2-q)} < \infty \, .
\end{align}

---

In order to find the exact value of $c$ we need to introduce [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). Since $z_1 = r \cos(\varphi_1)$, the integrand depends on the angle $\varphi_1$ and only the integrations over $\varphi_2, \dots, \varphi_{n-1}$ are trivial. Therefore, we need to divide the prefactor $\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ by the contribution of the $\varphi_1$-integral:
$$ c = \frac{\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}{\int_0^\pi \sin^{n-2}(\varphi_1) \, \mathrm{d} \varphi_1} \int \limits_0^\pi \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{1 - \cos(r \cos(\varphi_1))}{r^{n+q}} r^{n-1} \sin^{n-2} (\varphi_1) \, \mathrm{d} r \, \mathrm{d} \varphi_1 \, .$$
The integral in the denominator is a [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) integral. The remaining double integral can be simplified by exploiting the symmetry of the integrand about $\varphi_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and integrating by parts with respect to $r$:
$$ c = \frac{\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}{\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \frac{2}{q} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin(r \cos(\varphi_1))}{r^q} \cos(\varphi_1) \sin^{n-2}(\varphi_1) \, \mathrm{d} r \, \mathrm{d} \varphi_1 \, .$$
Finally, the change of variables $u = r \cos(\varphi_1)$ leads to two independent integrals. One of them is another beta function integral and the other has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454600/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinaxxb-dx) (we can simplify the result by applying the gamma function reflection formula). We find
\begin{align}
c &= \frac{\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}{\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \frac{2}{q} \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n-2}(\varphi_1) \cos^{q}(\varphi_1) \, \mathrm{d} \varphi_1 \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u^q} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}{\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{q} \operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{q+1}{2}\right) \frac{\pi}{2 \operatorname{\Gamma}(q) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} q\right)} \, .
\end{align}
After plugging in the known values for the surface area and the beta function we arrive at
$$ c = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} q\right) \operatorname{\Gamma}(q + 1) \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{q+n}{2}\right)} \, . $$
In particular, for $q=1$ we have
$$ c = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)} \, . $$

Comment: Thank you! Where does the $\frac{|y|^{n+q}}{|y|^{n}}$ term come from in the second line when you express the integral in terms of $z$?

Comment: @mhan $\lvert y \rvert^{n+q}$ comes from the denominator $\lvert x \rvert^{n+q} = \frac{\lvert z \rvert^{n+q}}{\lvert y \rvert^{n+q}}$ and $\frac{1}{\lvert y \rvert^n}$ is the Jacobian determinant of the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can prove that your last one-dimensional integral is convergent:
At $r=\infty$ it is convergent, since $q+1>1$. At $r=0$ you have
$$
|x\cdot y|=r\|y\||\cos(x,y)|\le Cr
$$
for some positive constant $C=C(y)$. Therefore, using Taylor's expansion around zero, you have
$$
1-\cos(x\cdot y)\le \frac{C^2r^2}{2}
$$
for $r$ small and then
$$
\frac{1-\cos(x\cdot y)}{r^{1+q}}\le \frac{D}{r^{q-1}},
$$
Now the power $q-1<1$ since $q<2$ and it is convergent at the origin as well.