# integration of $\sin^3(x)/x^3 $ from $0$ to infinity.Can it be solved using laplace or fourier transform?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Integration of  $\sin^3(x)/x^3 $ from $0$ to infinity. Can it be solved using Laplace or Fourier transform ?

Comment: yes it can be solved that way...search the site properly it was demonstrated somewhere

Comment: I already tried..,if you can tell me I will be thankful to u

Comment: Have a look at :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453198/show-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin3xx3dx-frac3-pi8?noredirect=1&lq=1.