# How to integrate $(\sin x/x)^3$ from $0$ to $\infty$?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^\infty(\sin(x)/x)^3 dx$$
Help me!

Comment: You're missing a $dx$.  Have you tried using a contour and the residue theorem?

Comment: Also, see [show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\sin^3(x)}{x^3}dx=\frac{3\pi}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453198/show-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin3xx3dx-frac3-pi8)